# It is good practice to use name=arguments as function arguments in arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arrow-functions

Arrow functions do not have an array of arguments; how good is using `...arguments`? It will not break something in the future?

```js
const getStr = (...arguments) => [].slice.call(arguments, 1).join(arguments[0])
getStr( '*', '1', 'b', '1c' ) // '1*b*1c'
```

Comment: it's totally fine to use as these are specified in docs, there nothing to worry

Comment: Why not just do `...args`? It's less confusing on multiple levels and shorter.

Comment: Are you asking for this specific case? Because `const getStr = (joiner, ...rest) => rest.join(joiner)` would be much nicer.

Comment: I would refrain from naming the array `arguments` specifically because of the potential confusion. I would name it something, anything different: `args`, `argumentsArray`, for example. IMHO.

Comment: "*Arrow functions do not have an array of argument*" neither do normal functions. A normal function has the `arguments` *object* - it's not an array but an array-like. The difference is that you cannot use array methods on it, e.g., `function fn() { return arguments.map(x => x+1)}` is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions do not have a `arguments` of their own, so using a `arguments` as a parameter is not a problem but it might be confusing.

But an arrow function in the scope of an outer function has access to the `arguments` object of the outer function. So the arrow function can use the `arguments` of the outer function in its logic as shown below:

```js
const getStr = (...anotherArguments) => { 
  console.log("arguments here is ", typeof arguments); 
  return [].slice.call(anotherArguments, 1).join(anotherArguments[0]);
}
console.log(getStr( '*', '1', 'b', '1c' ));


function outer(){
  //arguments captured from the outer function scope
   return (() => { 
      console.log("arguments here is" , typeof arguments); 
      return [].slice.call(arguments, 1).join(arguments[0]); 
   })()
}
console.log(outer( '*', '1', 'b', '1c' ));
```

So if you have a parameter called `arguments` in your arrow function it would shadow the `arguments` from the outer function, if you have the arrow function in the outer function scope.